# Cisco CME Failing to Transfer Calls From SIP Trunk, via Watcher Button

Tags: cisco, sip, cisco-voip

So, I have run into an issue that is stumping me. I have a Cisco 2811 running 15.1(3)T4, and I am using it to run CME on a small (three phone) VoIP system. The system has a SIP trunk through Vitelity. as well as a POTS line (for failover, as well as 911 calling.)

The primary receptionist has watch lines (meaning, "button 5w3", etc.) for the other two phones. When I cut them over to the SIP trunk, all of a sudden, she cannot use those buttons to transfer calls, but ONLY when they come in over the SIP trunk...calls that enter via the POTS line transfer correctly. She CAN transfer normally if she types their extension manually, as opposed to using the watch buttons. So, to summarize what is happening:

```
Incoming call via POTS -> Receptionist -> Transfer using Trnsfer+watch button -> Success
Incoming call via POTS -> Receptionist -> Transfer using Trnsfer+dialing extension -> Success
Incoming call via SIP Trunk -> Receptionist -> Transfer using Trnsfer+dialing extension -> Success
Incoming call via SIP Trunk -> Receptionist -> Transfer using Trnsfer+watch button -> Call drops
```

Any idea what is going on here? I have already set "voice service voip" -> "sip" -> "no update-callerid". Thanks!